# What are the blue atomic groupings/tags in MacOS and iOS apps' text field controls called? And is it a standard OS feature?

Tags: ios, cocoa, macos

I have no idea how to call these and so I'm having a hard time googling for it.  I've seen these a several times in iOS and MacOS apps to think they might be an OS feature.  I'm talking about the blue tags or groups in text field controls.  See the images below.

[image: Mail.app]

[image: Telephone.app]

Comment: If I was going to make up a name, I'd call them ["cartouches"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartouche).

Comment: I like it!  How about "little [blue pills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill)" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [`NSTokenField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on Mac.  On iOS there's no official implementation ([file a request if you want one](http://bugreport.apple.com)) so you'd have to go with a third-party implementation.  If I remember correctly, the Three20 framework has one...

Googling found these iOS versions:

- [`JSTokenField`](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField)
- [`TTMessageRecipientField`](http://api.Three20.info/interface_t_t_message_recipient_field.php) (I *think*)

Answer (score 0):

This helper class is SO much better... https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenFieldView

Comment: To begin with, unlike JSTokenField, it relies on Core Graphics to draw the gradient bubble. Plus, it also has inline search functionality (it kinda imitates UISearchDisplayController behavior).

Comment: Just make sure you take note of the license: http://thermoglobalnuclearwar.com/opensource/license.txt