# iOS: how can I mimic the 'to' field?

Tags: ios, email

I'm writing an app that will periodically open an email for the user to email to a predetermined list of contacts in iOS.  I have a text field, and I'm going to allow the user to add email addresses to the text field both from selecting email addresses from the contact list and to enter them by hand.  When entering by hand, I want to be able to autocomplete email addresses in the contact book, much like the 'to' field in the mail app.  How can I do this autocompletion?

Comment: I know what you are referring to but I would recommend including a screenshot.

Comment: @Joe-- what would you want the screenshot to show?  The blue circle or an autocomplete on a textfield that isn't the 'to' field?

Comment: See how [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237713/what-are-the-blue-atomic-groupings-tags-in-macos-and-ios-apps-text-field-contro) (which partially answers your question) added pictures, it just helps to include pictures in your post when you are asking how to replicate a UI feature.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question as well, were you asking about the "blue pill" look or actually how to implement auto completion in general.

Comment: @Joe-- both :)  Let me see what I can put together.

Answer (score 2):

You will first construct a dictionary of the possible email addresses and a string you want to match (that is, a name might be Fred Smith but the email might be f15smith@gmail.com).

Your "To" entry will be a UITextField, and to get the current string with the possibility of autocomplete you will populate some list and show it under the UITextField.

To get characters as the user types, implement this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

The new string will be the current string (myTextField.text) with the "range" of characters replaced by string. The result is the string to update your match list. Just return YES from this method.

When a user clicks on a contact in your list, you will simply replace the To text with whatever contact the person selected.